# VBA, Font size change when writing variable to cells

Tags: excel, vba

I currently write my variable `page_title` to cells.
I cannot seem to alter the font size though.

This currently loops through column B, Adds one to each row and writes my variable.

```
Sheets("stack").Range("B" & max_row_front + 1).value = page_title
```

However I want to change the font on the destination sheet(`stack`), not where it came from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `.Font.Size` ?

```
Dim fontSize As Integer: fontSize = 14
Sheets("stack").Range("B" & max_row_front + 1).Font.Size = fontSize
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to change font and size of the 'page_title' value.

```
With Sheets("stack").Range("B" & max_row_front + 1)
    .Value = page_title
    .Font.Name = "Courier New" 'You can change it for your favorite font ;)
    .Font.Size = 11
End With
```

hope this can help you.